# How i can read the line on my ".txt"?

Tags: c#

I am a big newbie, so I need your Help!

How i can read the line on my ".txt"?
Why does not the query work in the game? Or The comparison with 
(password = .txt) file?

```
[Command("log")]
public void login3(Client player, string passwort)
{
    var sender = API.getPlayerName(player);

    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(player + ".txt"));
    {
        using (StreamReader leser = new StreamReader(player + ".txt"))
        if ((passwort = leser.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Erfolgreich eingeloggt!");
        }
        else
        {
            API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Passwort falsch!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `==` not `=`.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific as to what is going on. `ReadLine` is indead the right answer here. Also, don't store passwords in plaintext **ever**

Comment: Why two `StreamReader`s?

Comment: Just a comment, if this is any sort of real code, getting a password from a file like this is a massive security issue. It's fine for just playing around locally.

Comment: Sorry only one StreamReader!The problem is that the query does not work I can always log in!

Comment: another problem is you assign `sender` but don't use it, I think your file name is wrong because of it.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have already pointed out your main problem. You are assigning `passwort`, not comparing it because you are using the single `=` operator. For comparisons you use `==`.

Additionally, you have an unused `StreamReader`, and the one you do use is not properly disposed.

Lastly, after you fix the double ==, you must not do a null check because neither true nor false is null. Check if the line contents equal the password.

Try this:

```
[Command("log")]
public void login3(Client player, string passwort)
{
    var sender = API.getPlayerName(player);

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(sender + ".txt")))
    {
        // use double ==
        // check if line contents equal to password, not null, because false is not null too
        if (passwort == reader.ReadLine())
        {
            API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Erfolgreich eingeloggt!");
        }
        else
        {
            API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Passwort falsch!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `File.ReadLines` and *Linq* instead of `StreamReader`:

```
[Command("log")]
public void login3(Client player, string passwort)
{
    //DONE: validate public method's arguments
    if (null == player) 
      throw new ArgumentNullException("player");
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) 
      return; // Player doesn't have a password

    // Read the first line of the file and compare it with the password 
    if (File
          .ReadLines(player + ".txt") //TODO: implement as a property: player.FileName
          .Take(1)
          .Any(line => line == passwort)) 
      API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Erfolgreich eingeloggt!");
    else
      API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Passwort falsch!");
}
```

Comment: So i did like you said. And i got no errors in the Code. But when i try to logg in (in the game itsself) its says 1x peer Second : Passwort falsch!

Comment: @Kristoff.Ulrich: what does *corresponding txt file* contain? And what is the input?

Comment: In the text file are the Passwort and the Username, but in near future i also want the value of money or Lvl be safed in this file.
 The input is a gameserver for gtaV.
Im very sorry for my bad english ;/

Comment: @Kristoff.Ulrich: Could you provide an *example* of the text file and the *exepected password value* extracted?

Comment: hmm i see its not good explanation from my site.
I want when a Client(Player) joins the Gameserver that he type /register (name) (passwort). This is then safed in a .txt file. After that he has to login. 
but when he Login its not working. 
In the code are no errors. And i cant pastedown the Code rightnow..

Comment: I would expect some kind of error being thrown, but I doubt `player + ".txt"` will result in the correct file name, I believe it should be `sender + ".txt"` (assignment of `sender` in original question)